# Laravel sanctum on product/staging server returning 401 after successful login

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-sanctum

I am working on a web application at the moment that has a an api at the top level domain (mydomain.com) and an SPA at subdomain (spa.mydomain.com). In the SPA I have added,

`axios.defaults.withCredentials = true`

To login in I run the following code,

```
axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie').then(response => {
    axios.post('/login', {email: this.email, password: this.password}).then(response => {
      this.$router.push({ name: 'Account' });
    });
  });
```

The get request responds with a 204 as expected and the post request to login responds successfully too, at this point I get redirected and another GET is sent to /api/users/me at this point the server responds with a 401 unauthorized response.

I would have assumed that seen as though I can login everything would be working as expected but sadly not, the key bits of my `.env` file from my api are below to see if I am missing anything obvious.

`SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
SESSION_DOMAIN=.mydomain.com
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=spa.mydomain.com`

My request headers look like this,

`Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6InZDRTAvenNlRGhwdVNzY2p5VUFQeFE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiVzBLT0wyNTI2Vk5la3hiQ1M1TXpRU2pRQ3pXeGk1Nkc1eW5QN0F5ZjNFUmdIVmlaWGNqdXZVcU9UYUNVTzhXbiIsIm1hYyI6IjJmMmIyMjc4MzNkODA4ZDdlZjRhZTJhM2RlMTQ5NDg1MWM2MjdhMzdkMTFjZGNiMzdkMDM3YjNjNzM1ZmY5NjAifQ%3D%3D; at_home_club_session=eyJpdiI6ImxLYjlRNHplcGh1d2RVSEtnakxJNmc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiWnBjN0xheWlaNDdDUWZnZGxMUzlsM0VzbjZaZVdUSTBZL0R1WXRTTGp5emY0S2NodGZNN25hQmF1ajYzZzU3MiIsIm1hYyI6ImNlMWRmNWJhYmE1ODU3MzM1Y2Q4ZDI0MDIzNTU1OWQ4MDE3MGRiNTJjY2NjNmFmZDU5YzhjZTM4NGJlOGU5ZTkifQ%3D%3D; XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6ImhadVF0eHlEY3l4RWtnZk45MmVxZ2c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiRCs4QkNMRjBodzJKaFIvRVQwZUZlM3BzYmlJMGp0Y0E5RXdHdkYrblVzSzNPQTJZbE42ZlhlYllmWlg2a0ltMSIsIm1hYyI6IjA1NWU0ZjFiNDFjN2VkNjNiMzJiNjFlNTFiMjBmNWE3MzA4Yzk1YmJiNzdmZGUyZmZhNjcwYmQxZTYxYTBmY2QifQ%3D%3D; at_home_club_session=eyJpdiI6IjZxWXZSYjdGWXU5SHBKSFFRdGQycWc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiU3RyTDdoNGJBUW93ck9CTmFjVFpjRTRxMVVwQzZmcjJJTXJUNFU0UUZVcnkzcWdBbzZxWjNvTWZrZmFuMXBrbSIsIm1hYyI6IjFkOTFiNDg5YmZjYmE0NGZiZDg3ZGY5ZDQyMDg2MGZjNzFlMmI0OTA1OGY2MzdkMmFmOGI0ZTlkOTE4ZDM0NWUifQ%3D%3D; XLtgHBp79G2IlVzFPoHViq4wcAV1TMveovlNr1V4=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%3D
Host: mydomain.com
Origin: http://spa.mydomain.com
Referer: http://spa.mydomain.info/account
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36
X-XSRF-TOKEN: eyJpdiI6ImhadVF0eHlEY3l4RWtnZk45MmVxZ2c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiRCs4QkNMRjBodzJKaFIvRVQwZUZlM3BzYmlJMGp0Y0E5RXdHdkYrblVzSzNPQTJZbE42ZlhlYllmWlg2a0ltMSIsIm1hYyI6IjA1NWU0ZjFiNDFjN2VkNjNiMzJiNjFlNTFiMjBmNWE3MzA4Yzk1YmJiNzdmZGUyZmZhNjcwYmQxZTYxYTBmY2QifQ==`

and my cors,

```
'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie', 'login'],

'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

'exposed_headers' => [],

'max_age' => 0,

'supports_credentials' => true,
```

Everything works perfectly on localhost.

Comment: what is your `cors` setting ? can you show that too ?

Comment: @AkhtarMunir added for you.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm getting the same issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using `tokenType: ''` in the Nuxt auth config

```
  axios: {
    baseURL: process.env.BASE_URL,
    credentials: true,
    maxBodyLength: 100 * 1024 * 1024,
    maxContentLength: 100 * 1024 * 1024,
    timeout: 10000
  },



auth: {
    redirect: {
      login: '/',
      logout: '/',
      callback: '/',
      home: '/dashboard'
    },
    strategies: {
      local: {
        endpoints: {
          login: {
            url: process.env.API_ROUTE + '/login',
            method: 'post',
            propertyName: 'token'
          },
          logout: {
            url: process.env.API_ROUTE + '/logout',
            method: 'post',
            propertyName: 'logout'
          },
          user: {
            url: process.env.API_ROUTE + '/user',
            method: 'get',
            propertyName: false
          }
        }
      }
    },
    tokenType: ''
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by changing cookie name.
You can change it in config/session.php file

By default it is

```
'cookie' => env(
        'SESSION_COOKIE',
        Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_') . '_session'
    ),
```

Make it different for different subdomains

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i resolve similar problem by add my new ip in stateful domain in folder config/sanctum.php